# AHKV1: With ControlGet, Is it possible to also get the column header names along with the items?

Tags: autohotkey

I am able to get the items of a `SysListView321` using `ControlGet`:

```
ControlGet, OutputVar, List,, SysListView321, Options ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe Ditto.exe
Console(OutputVar)
```

`Console()` outputs:

```
    Apply Last Search
Alt + C Cancel Filter
Alt + ENTER Clip Properties
ESC Close Window
Ctrl + F2   Compare Selected Clips
Ctrl + C    Copy Selection
    Decrease Transparency %
    Delete all non used clips
    Delete Clip Data
Ctrl + E    Edit Clip
    EMail, Clip Export As Attachment
    EMail, Content As Attachment
    EMail, Content In Body
    Export To Google Translate
    Export To Image File
    Export To QR Code
    Export To Text File
    Filter On Selected Clip
Shift + ESC Force Close Window
    Global HotKeys
    Gmail
...
```

This is neat. But is it possible to also include the names of the column headers as well?

For example, in the [WINDOW](https://i.imgur.com/xMjb5je.png) I am working with, the headers are `Hot key` and `Command`. I searched around but could not find anything.

Perhaps this is something that can be accomplished by another command? I am open to suggestion even if its an external library

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Probably only indirectly: `If InStr(OutputVar, "this unique text") --> MsgBox, column header names` In which context do you need  those names?

Comment: Or try this [example](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ControlGetPos.htm#ExBasic) to get the control of the column headers, in case Window Spy cannot "see" them.

Comment: No that did not take either unfortunetly. But thank you though.  I did find a soution though, and I disclosed it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it thanks to this answer by [Alguimist](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=231012&sid=0450e5a57bd16d962534c943c1110990#p231012). Of all the potential solution's, theirs was the only one that would let me do it remotely, that is without activating the controls window.

It was critical that I achieve a means to do it 'remotely' as I was intending to use it for a PowerShell module that gets the value of a windows control, such as combo box, button, edit etc.
[image]

Alguimist's source code:

```
    ;https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=231012#p231012
    ; Returns an object containing the text and width of each item of a remote SysHeader32 control
    CTRL_GetHeader(hHeader){
        Static MAX_TEXT_LENGTH := 260
            , MAX_TEXT_SIZE := MAX_TEXT_LENGTH * (A_IsUnicode ? 2 : 1)

        WinGet PID, PID, ahk_id %hHeader%

        ; Open the process for read/write and query info.
        ; PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION
        If !(hProc := DllCall("OpenProcess", "UInt", 0x438, "Int", False, "UInt", PID, "Ptr")) {
            Return
        }

        ; Should we use the 32-bit struct or the 64-bit struct?
        If (A_Is64bitOS) {
            Try DllCall("IsWow64Process", "Ptr", hProc, "int*", Is32bit := true)
        } Else {
            Is32bit := True
        }

        RPtrSize := Is32bit ? 4 : 8
        cbHDITEM := (4 * 6) + (RPtrSize * 6)

        ; Allocate a buffer in the (presumably) remote process.
        remote_item := DllCall("VirtualAllocEx", "Ptr", hProc, "Ptr", 0
                                    , "uPtr", cbHDITEM + MAX_TEXT_SIZE
                                    , "UInt", 0x1000, "UInt", 4, "Ptr") ; MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE
        remote_text := remote_item + cbHDITEM

        ; Prepare the HDITEM structure locally.
        VarSetCapacity(HDITEM, cbHDITEM, 0)
        NumPut(0x3, HDITEM, 0, "UInt") ; mask (HDI_WIDTH | HDI_TEXT)
        NumPut(remote_text, HDITEM, 8, "Ptr") ; pszText
        NumPut(MAX_TEXT_LENGTH, HDITEM, 8 + RPtrSize * 2, "Int") ; cchTextMax

        ; Write the local structure into the remote buffer.
        DllCall("WriteProcessMemory", "Ptr", hProc, "Ptr", remote_item, "Ptr", &HDITEM, "uPtr", cbHDITEM, "Ptr", 0)

        HDInfo := {}
        VarSetCapacity(HDText, MAX_TEXT_SIZE)

        SendMessage 0x1200, 0, 0,, ahk_id %hHeader% ; HDM_GETITEMCOUNT
        Loop % (ErrorLevel != "FAIL") ? ErrorLevel : 0 {
            ; Retrieve the item text.
            SendMessage, % (A_IsUnicode) ? 0x120B : 0x1203, A_Index - 1, remote_item,, ahk_id %hHeader% ; HDM_GETITEMW
            If (ErrorLevel == 1) { ; Success
                DllCall("ReadProcessMemory", "Ptr", hProc, "Ptr", remote_item, "Ptr", &HDITEM, "uPtr", cbHDITEM, "Ptr", 0)
                DllCall("ReadProcessMemory", "Ptr", hProc, "Ptr", remote_text, "Ptr", &HDText, "uPtr", MAX_TEXT_SIZE, "Ptr", 0)
            } Else {
                HDText := ""
            }

            HDInfo.Push({"Width": NumGet(HDITEM, 4, "UInt"), "Text": HDText})
        }

        ; Release the remote memory and handle.
        DllCall("VirtualFreeEx", "Ptr", hProc, "Ptr", remote_item, "UPtr", 0, "UInt", 0x8000) ; MEM_RELEASE
        DllCall("CloseHandle", "Ptr", hProc)

        Return HDInfo
    }
```